# web scraping a webpage with multiple tabs in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape the expiry dates data in R from the following webpage: https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=251#expiry. This page contain several tabs, the expiry date is only one of them. The code I use is

```
library(RCurl)
Canola <- 'https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=251#expiry'
WS <- getURL(Canola,ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
library(XML)
ParsedData <- htmlParse(WS)
CanolaExpDate <- readHTMLTable(ParsedData)
names(CanolaExpDate)
```

The final output is, however, the trading hours on the first tab-product specification.

I am new to web scraping,not knowledgeable about html.Please advise.

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Comment: I want to have all the data on the expiry date tab in a data.frame

Comment: Do you want to aceess you `CanolaExpDate` list? `CanolaExpDate$tradingHours` ??

Comment: I don't want the trading hours, i need the expiry date information. basically, i scraped the wrong data. the trading hour data is on product specification tab, the data i want is on the expiry date tab.

Comment: yes I konw that you want the expiry date. it is not clear for me which data is the expiry date ( not all people here has a financial background). That 's said , do you mean to extract all dates in the table mentioned by your link?  which column? FTD?LTD?.... that 'w why I demand the expected output.

Comment: FTD=first trading day, LTD=last trading day, LND=last notice day, LDD=last delivery day.  Most likely the OP is interested in FND (first notice date) as that is the first day that the long could be notified that the short is going to deliver, but I bet he'd be happy if you could get the whole table into a `data.frame`.  @Lawrence, for practical purposes, you probably just want the last trading date of the month prior to expiry; that's pretty easy to calculate and requires no web scraping.

Comment: Sorry about that. all the data on the expiry date tabs are expiry dates data for different contracts. I want them all. if you see the link posted, you can find a suffix #expiry. i think this specifies the tab. however, R didn't seem to process this suffix, only stops at https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=251.

Comment: @GSee,This is just an example. my goal is to grab all the expiry dates for all different products, not only this products. i want to automate this process using R.

Answer (score 1):

I searched through the source code of that page for "expiry" and saw how the URLs are formed.  Adding `&expiryDates` instead of `#expiry` leads to a table that is easier to parse.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
Canola <- "https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=251&expiryDates"
WS <- getURL(Canola)
x <- readHTMLTable(WS, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
as.data.frame(lapply(x[[1]], as.Date, format="%a %b %d %X"))

#   Contract.Symbol        FTD        LTD        FND        LND        FDD        LDD Options.FTD Options.LTD
#1       2013-07-01 2013-05-16 2013-07-12 2013-06-28 2013-07-15 2013-07-02 2013-07-16        <NA>  2013-06-21
#2       2013-08-01 2013-03-25 2013-07-26 2013-07-31 2013-08-15 2013-08-01 2013-08-16        <NA>  2013-07-26
#3       2013-09-01 2013-08-27 2013-08-23 2013-08-30 2013-09-16 2013-09-03 2013-09-17        <NA>  2013-08-23
#4       2013-10-01 2013-05-27 2013-09-20 2013-09-30 2013-10-15 2013-10-01 2013-10-16        <NA>  2013-09-20
#5       2013-11-01 2013-07-15 2013-11-14 2013-10-31 2013-11-15 2013-11-01 2013-11-18        <NA>  2013-10-25
#6       2013-01-01 2013-11-15 2013-01-14 2013-12-31 2013-01-15 2013-01-02 2013-01-16        <NA>  2013-12-20
#7       2013-03-01 2013-01-17 2013-03-14 2013-02-28 2013-03-17 2013-03-03 2013-03-18        <NA>  2013-02-21
#8       2013-05-01 2013-03-15 2013-05-14 2013-04-30 2013-05-15 2013-05-01 2013-05-16        <NA>  2013-04-25
#9       2013-07-01 2013-05-15 2013-07-14 2013-06-30 2013-07-15 2013-07-02 2013-07-16        <NA>  2013-06-20
#10      2013-11-01 2013-07-16 2013-11-14 2013-10-31 2013-11-17 2013-11-03 2013-11-18        <NA>  2013-10-24
#11      2013-01-01 2013-11-15 2013-01-14 2013-12-31 2013-01-15 2013-01-02 2013-01-16        <NA>  2013-12-19
#12      2013-03-01 2013-01-15 2013-03-13 2013-02-27 2013-03-16 2013-03-02 2013-03-17        <NA>  2013-02-20
#13      2013-05-01 2013-03-15 2013-05-14 2013-04-30 2013-05-15 2013-05-01 2013-05-19        <NA>  2013-04-24
#14      2013-07-01 2013-05-15 2013-07-14 2013-06-30 2013-07-15 2013-07-02 2013-07-16        <NA>  2013-06-26
```

---

Edit: More on how I found the URL I used above.  I actually didn't use any developer tools.  I just right-clicked and selected "view source" and searched for "expiry".  There's an `app.urls` section that has something like this

```
'expiry':'/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml;jsessionid=C59BE223F113CFDD340BF23CC07EEFFC?expiryDates=&specId=251'
```

So, I tried omitting the jsessionid part and I went to

```
https://theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?expiryDates=&specId=251
```

and it looked interesting.  I only reordered it to `https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=251&expiryDates`

because I thought the URL looked nicer like that.

Comment: Is finding `&expiryDates` something you can find using the developer tools in chrome? How did you find that this in the source?

Comment: @GSee. it works very well, thanks.@cyclondude, yes, you can see the source in developers tools and search for 'expiry'